# Why do I get undefined function isset() on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, isset, laravel-excel, laravel-queue

we are using Laravel Excel package and running it on the queue (on Supervisor). Sometimes it works perfect and sometimes I get

`Call to undefined function App\Imports\ isset() error`

on failed jobs table. And ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the future, please just copy-paste code and errors into the editor. Screenshots are not easy to read for all users, and it makes it difficult to detect errors in encoding.

Answer (score 2):

You have used Turkish char `i̇` on `i̇sset` replace it with `isset` will resolve your issue:

```php
var_dump(mb_strtoupper('i̇sset')); //Your turkish i̇sset: string(7) "İSSET"
var_dump(mb_strtoupper('isset')); //Correct isset: string(5) "ISSET"
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's the problem but worth to try. I changed all "i" characters. Thank you for suggestion.